# Images not loaded when using .mtl and .obj files

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to load an `.mtl` and an `.obj` file. From what I can see that is rendered, we get the `.obj`, somewhat correctly:

[image]

However if I load the same `.obj` file in Blender I get this:

[image]

Here is the `.mtl` file that is associated with the `.obj` which refers to `.tif` and `.jpg` files that are in the exact same folder:

```
newmtl Material_01_01
Ns 10.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 0.6627 0.6471 0.6471
Kd 0.6627 0.6471 0.6471
Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000

newmtl Material_01_02
Ns 10.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 0.6627 0.6471 0.6471
Kd 0.6627 0.6471 0.6471
Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
map_Ka Map_01.tif
map_Kd Map_01.tif

newmtl Material_01_03
Ns 10.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Kd 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000

newmtl Material_01_04
Ns 10.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 0.6627 0.6471 0.6471
Kd 0.6627 0.6471 0.6471
Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
map_Ka Map_02.jpg
map_Kd Map_02.jpg
```

I've looked at mrdoobs' implementation of the `OBJLoader` and `MTLLoader` [here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html) and have implemented it exactly but I don't get either the images nor the grey colour. Why?

```
  let canvas = {}, shape, objLoader;
  let manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

  const PATH = 'http://localhost:8080/';
  const FILENAME = 'Sample_01_OBJ';

  let mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setPath(PATH)

  mtlLoader.load(FILENAME+'.mtl', (materials) => {
    materials.preload();

    objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath(PATH);

    this.setup(canvas, true, false);
    this.image = image;

    objLoader.load(FILENAME+'.obj', (obj) => {
      canvas['scene'].add(obj);
      canvas['shape'] = obj;

      this.addRendererToElement(EXAMPLE_ITEMS, canvas);
      this.addCameraControls(canvas);
      this.render(canvas, canvas['update'], 'blender0');
    });
  });
```

Comment: I'm afraid TIFF images are not supported by web browsers.

Comment: @Matey but the second one is a JPG and that doesn't display either

Comment: You haven't said if you'd applied a light source. It'll be black if you don't. Are you getting a 404 in your console on the image paths?

Comment: @Radio applying the lightsource does make a difference. I can see the images though it doesn't match what it should

Comment: The next thing to do then is to check the UV mapping and normals from your 3d editor that produced the obj and mtl and be sure they're being exported. The obj files will have lines that begin with "vt" which define the coordinates.

Comment: @Radio Thanks for the further information. The .obj file does indeed contain the vt lines so they are being exported. The reason that I said that it doesn't match what it should is because the company that created the model sent a screenshot of what it should look like, yet the Blender version of this doesn't match that screenshot. Can you add your comment regarding the light as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: An actual answer to the question would not contain code that corrects or informs. Had the question been "how do I set up a light in three.js" or "why isn't this light working in three.js" an answer would be required. You know how to work with lights. It was just an oversight. Thank you for the considerateness of your request though.

Comment: @Radio cheers Jeff